# Scala "type" alias confusion

Tags: scala

I am working on Coursera Assignment and in Week 2. This week assignment is not tough but very confusing.

I wrote below code and it works fine

```
def union(s:Set[Int], t:Set[Int]):Set[Int] = s union t
```

But if I use type to create alias of Set and rewrite above as

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def union(s:Set, t:Set):Set = s union t
```

Now I get error for union is not a member of Set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def union(s:Set[Int], t:Set[Int]):Set[Int] = s union t
```

This works because `Set[T]` defines a function named `union`, which is called in the above code.

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def union(s:Set, t:Set):Set = s union t
```

This doesn't work because functions don't have a method named `union`.

Comment: Isn't type just aliasing Set[Int] ?

Comment: @DarkStar No, it's creating a new type called `Set` that has nothing to do with the standard library class called `Set`. That new type `Set` is an alias for `Int => Boolean`. That is when you write `def union(s: Set, t: Set): Set`, that's the same as writing `def union(s: Int => Boolean, t: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean`.

Comment: Thanks you said it correct. The moment I used type `Set = Int => Boolean`, it created a new function alias, which takes an integer and returns a boolean. So I give you +1 too for clarification. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

From what I can remember way back when I did that course, you are not supposed to use any standard library types to build your solutions. So you are not supposed to use `Set[T]` from the standard library. In the collection library, `union` is defined and works as expected.

However, the course requires you to define your own type for `Set` and I believe it is `Int => Boolean`.

What you actually need is a function like this:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
def union (s1 : Set, s2 : Set) : Set = (x:Int) => s1(x) || s2(x)
```

That is, you need to define a lambda.

Comment: Thanks. Actually @kpbochenek mentioned is more precisely but you connected the link after his solution so I gave you also +1

Answer (score 1):

You already have `union` function present in scala. You can verify in repl by doing:

```
> val x: Set[Int] = Set(1,2,3)
> x.union(Set(3, 4, 5))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Let's say you want to define your own function to do exactly the same thing, you can write:

`def myunion[T](x: Set[T], y: Set[T]): Set[T] = x.union(y)`

This is generic method(just like in set) and you can call it:

```
> myunion(Set(1, 2, 3), Set(3, 4, 5))
//but it also works for other types:
> myunion(Set('a', 'b', 'c'), Set('c', 'd', 'e'))
```

Aliasing type is done with slightly different syntax:

```
type SetInt = Set[Int]
type SetChar = Set[Char]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I needed clarity on my issue and you answered it correctly

Answer (score 1):

When you do `type Set = Int => Boolean`, you create `Function1` type. 
You can check it by yourself in scala repl;

```
scala> type Set = Int => Boolean
defined type alias Set

scala> val test: Set = i => true
test: Set = <function1>
```

As you see in [Function1[-T1, +R]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.Function1) trait extends `AnyRef` which doesn't have `union` method but [Set](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.Set) has it.